# Ignoring zero division error

Tags: python, zero

I'm writing a program that reads integer values from an input file, divides the numbers, then writes percentages to an output file. Some of the values that my program may be zero, and bring up a 0/0 or 4/0 occasion.

From here, I get a Zerodivisionerror, is there a way to ignore this error so that it simply prints 0%??

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO ,please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it'll be helping you to put your content quality up .

Answer (score 4):

The easiest option is to check if divisor is `0` and if that's the case skip the division and just use `0` as result:

```
n = [(1, 3), (5, 2), (0, 0), (3, 3), (4, 0)]
res = [x / float(y) if y else 0 for x, y in n] # [0.3333333333333333, 2.5, 0, 1.0, 0]
```

Other option is to catch `ZeroDivisionError` with `try`/`except`:

```
res = []
for x, y in n:
    try:
        res.append(x / float(y))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        res.append(0)
```